# Infinite Perfect Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-graphs

A graph $G$ is perfect if every induced subgraph $H$ of $G$ can be coloured with $k$ colours, where $k$ is the size of a largest clique in $H$.

The Perfect Graph Theorem (conjectured by Berge and proved by Lovasz) states that if $G$ is perfect, then its complement is. My question: to what extent if any is the perfect graph theorem true for infinite graphs?

Comment: Do you require that the largest clique in $H$ is finite?

Comment: Cliques, neighbourhoods etc can be infinite.

Comment: What have you found since you first posted your question?